# Can arcpy let the user enter a query expression for select layer by attribute?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I have written something like this:

```
inFc = sys.argv[1]    
FLayer = sys.argv[2]    
FValue = sys.argv[3]    
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFc, FLayer) #feature layer created    
arcpy.AddMessage ("Layer has been created")    
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(FLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", " FValue ")
```

In my parameters, I have inFc set as an input feature class, FLayer as the output feature layer, and FValue as an input query expression. I also clicked "obtain the data from the input feature class" for the FValue query. When I do this, however, it presents an error. I'm sure it has something to do with the user-entered query.

Comment: What data type is argument 3? Can you include a screen shot of the tool properties for argument 3 please.

Comment: Don't put quotes around your variable `FValue`.